# Unified use of javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror and java.lang.Class

Tags: java, class, types, annotation-processing

I have an interface containing a method accepting an object of type java.lang.Class

```
public interface TypeReviewer {
    public int evaluate(Class<?> type);

    ...
}
```

Now I want to support the use of objects of this interface in an annotation processor.
But, as some classes might not have been compiled during annotation processing, it seems that I need to add a method

```
    public int evaluate(TypeMirror type)
```

to the interface. (I may need to add a parameter of type javax.lang.model.util.Types as well but that doesn't matter for the upcoming question)

To me it makes no sense to add this method to the interface as it should calculate exactly the same value for javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror and the TypeMirror basically represents the Class.
It is also a possible point of failure as a programmer whose implementing this interface in a class might produce different results in those methods for exactly the same type.

That leads me to my question:
What can I do to avoid this kind of redundant implementation for annotation processing and any other meta programming field?

Comment: How are you using this class in your annotation processor?

Comment: I am searching for TypeElements with a particular annotation and then I am using the asType() method of the annotated typelement to get the TypeMirror object.
The implementation of the TypeReviewer varies as I am instantiating those objects via some reflections.

Comment: So the interface is solely for use within the annotation processor? And are you trying to enforce the requirement that the type that the TypeMirror represents, should be part of the interface contract?

Comment: Not exactly. I need the implentations of the interface in usual code as well. I want to avoid using multiple methods.

For example: The evaluate method checks if the class is a subtype of a specific class. If it is, return 1 and if not return 0 (just a simple example)

For java.lang.Class I would write SpecificClass.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)

and for javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror I would write 
typeUtils.isSubtype(mirror,
elementUtils.getTypeElement("pkg.SpecificClass").asType());

It is the same implementation and I am looking for a way to avoid this kind of duplicate implementation.

Comment: I would separate the implementations and create an entirely different interface for use in annotation processing. Annotation processing occurs during compilation, and IMO it doesn't make sense to mix concerns (runtime vs. compile-time) inside a single interface; it is likely to be very confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At runtime you will not have access to TypeMirror instances.  At compile time you will not have access to all Class instances.  Therefore there is no single unified option.  The best solution I could think of (which may be appropriate depending on the complexity of your application) is to build your own simplified type API.  Here's a rough sketch:

```
public interface MyType {

    public boolean isSubclassOf(MyType otherType);

}

public class MyTypeClassImpl implements MyType {

    private Class<?> clazz;

    public MyTypeClassImpl(Class<?> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public boolean isSubclassOf(MyType otherType) {
        if(otherType instanceof MyTypeClassImpl) {
            return clazz.isAssignableFrom(((MyTypeClassImpl)otherType).clazz);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("TypeMirror encountered in non-annotation-processing environment");
        }
    }

}

//Similar implementation for type mirrors

public interface TypeFactory {

    public MyType fromJavaType(Object type);

}

public class AnnotationProcessorTypeFactory {

    private ProcessingEnvironment processingEnv;

    public MyType fromJavaType(Object type) {
        if(type instanceof TypeMirror) {
            return MyTypeMirrorImpl((TypeMirror)type);
        } else if (type instanceof Class<?>) {
            return MyTypeMirrorImpl(convertToTypeMirror((Class<?>)type));
        }
    }

    private TypeMirror convertToTypeMirror(Class<?> clazz) {
        return processingEnv.getElementUtils().getTypeElement(clazz.getCanonincalName());
    }

}

public class RuntimeTypeFactory implements TypeFactory {

    public MyType fromJavaType(Object type) {
        if(!(type instanceof Class<?>)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Illegal use of non-class type in runtime environment");
        }
        return new MyTypeClassImpl((Class<?>)type);
    }

}
```

Comment: for cross usage in meta fields and runtime fields, especially in my cases, this seems to be the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There is no unified abstraction over moth models provided at the moment.

There was/is [JEP 119](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/119) ("javax.lang.model Implementation Backed by Core Reflection") which unfortunately has not been included into the JDK yet. This [blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/core_backed_lang_model) by Joe Darcy shines some light on it and there also used to be a prototypical implementation somewhere in the OpenJDK repository, but I cannot find it anymore.

Comment: According to http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdk8-dev/2014-January/003922.html, it was not included in the final release: "we are *not* including the JEP 119 code as part of the API of the 
JDK -- it is neither a Java SE API (in java.* or javax.*) nor is it a 
supported JDK-specific API (in jdk.* or elsewhere). The implementation 
code is just a proof-of-concept sample."